# PyCharm skeleton for dynamically included .so files

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I'm packaging OpenCV with my Python application via a dynamic import. PyCharm is unable to generate skeletons for OpenCV though, even though the application runs fine. The project structure is as follows:

```
module/
    cv2/
        __init__.py
        cv2.so
    __init__.py
```

Now I'm making `module/cv2/__init__.py` call `cv2.so` dynamically:

```
import pkg_resources
import imp

__file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, "cv2.so")
imp.load_dynamic(__name__, __file__)
```

Finally `module/__init__.py` contains an import and prints an arbitrary constant:

```
from module import cv2

print(cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

The application runs as expected and prints the value of the constant. However, PyCharm says it cannot find the reference.

How can I have PyCharm detect a dynamically included module's skeleton? Or alternatively, how can I package and import the `.so` file statically?